# Showing Badges in iPhone Hybrid Application

Tags: iphone

We are developing a hybrid iPhone application. It has a webview that loads some mobile website. Website requires user authentication and once user is authenticated we need to show badge count for unread messages.

We are looking to use Push Notification to show badge count but I am not sure how should we register for push notification dynamically once user log-in and de-register once user log-out.

I believe if we can have some way to invoke native class method through javascript then we can achieve it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple whenever user logged-in, post a entry into the db and send notification for the records entered into the db and when user logging-out delete the entry from db

Comment: I believe we need Device Id to send push notification. How can we retrieve that using Javascript?

Comment: not throught javascript but you can send deviceid into the querystring  
or you can also post deviceid when you make a connection

Comment: Thanks! I believe deviceid can be retrieve only using native code and how to pass that value to my web application on a particular event that occurs within web view i.e Some Page Loads. Is there any way WebView can listen for certain events i.e. Page Load?

Comment: use 'UIWebViewDelegate' methods